# Search Orders on BrightPearl API

Tags: c#-4.0, brightpearl

I am trying to search BrightPearl orders through API using the following URL pattern using REST API

order-service/order-search?createdOn/2018-09-12T00:00:00/2018-09-12T23:59:59

This is how their documentation says. But it is not returning orders as expected within the date range instead, it returns all the orders available in the store regardless of the date range we applied.

Can anyone say the correct URL pattern which fulfills my requirement?
Please note that it is not a coding issue but URL pattern issue. If someone came across this problem earlier and fixed could help

```
http://api-docs.brightpearl.com/order/order/search.html

https://help.brightpearl.com/hc/en-us/articles/212644983-Resource-search?flash_digest=187c68ecc5151c9d3a390e14fd8e4f114db11bcd#autolink-heading-2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from the bright pearl support which solved my issue. Let me share it here

> It looks like you are using the wrong string.
>
> If you are using GET method the URL endpoint should look like this
>
> /order/*/goods-note/goods-out/20
>
> and if you are using PUT method the endpoint should look like this
>
> /warehouse-service/goods-note/goods-out/20
>
> This guide might help with the syntax: http://api-docs.brightpearl.com/warehouse/goods-out-note/get.html